# Unable to start BlueJ as sudo

Tags: raspbian, setup, sudo

I am new to raspberry pi devices. I am using the minimal image of the raspbian image and access my raspberry pi zero w using MobaXterm client. The issue is, when I run BlueJ directly through terminal, it runs but I am unable to create a project as Bluej might not have write permissions on rasp pi. But if I try to run it with the sudo command. It gives me the following error.

```
    MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1296)
        at bluej.Boot.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at bluej.Boot.main(Unknown Source)
```

[image: BlueJ running without sudo command]

Please, let me know if anything needs to be edited/added to the question.

Comment: What is the question? That sentence with question mark?

Comment: How do I start bluej with sudo privileges?